# 3rd level of inverted comma (didn't get proper title)

Tags: java, html, css, jsf-2, styles

I am creating web application using jsf 2.0. I have command button where style is as below.

What I have is

```
style="#{patentInfo.photoType.contains('application')?'visibility:visible;background-image: url(DisplayImage?mainID=tempo1;id=1)':'visibility:hidden;'
```

In **DisplayImage.java** below is what I have

```
String mainID = request.getParameter("mainID");
String whatString = request.getParameter("id");
System.out.println("mainID=="+mainID+", whatString=="+whatString);
```

Output I was expecting is

```
mainID==tempo1, whatString==1
```

however I am getting it as

```
mainID==tempo1;id=1, whatString==null
              ^^^^^
```

That means I would need to use third separator like ", ' after `url(DisplayImage?mainID=tempo1;id=1)`

i.e. something like

```
url(@DisplayImage?mainID=tempo1;id=1@)
    ^                               ^
```

Just curious, is there third level separator like inverted comma we have?

Please suggest me what should I do?

---

### Edit 1

If I use like below, it works perfectly as I have used only 2 levels as " and '.

```
style="background-image: url('DisplayImage?mainID=tempo1;id=1')"
```

I need solution for third level.

Comment: And I'm curious, why `&` can't be used as a params separator here (instead of `;`)?

Comment: @raina77ow : Do you mean `url(DisplayImage?mainID=tempo1&id=1)` ??

Comment: @raina77ow — Who says it can't?

Comment: @Quentin Well, somehow the OP didn't use it, hence my question. )

Comment: @raina77ow : this gives me error as `The reference to entity "id" must end with the ';' delimiter.`. Even if I use `url(DisplayImage?mainID=tempo1&id=1;)`, I get same error.

Comment: Shame `getParameter` doesn't appear to follow [this 15 year old recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL parameter separators are `?` and `&`.
you can use `url(DisplayImage?mainID=tempo1&id=1)`

Comment: this gives me error as `The reference to entity "id" must end with the ';' delimiter.`. Even if I use `url(DisplayImage?mainID=tempo1&id=1;)`, I get same error.

Comment: If you are putting a `&` in HTML or XML then it should be represented as `&amp;` (since `&` means "start of entity")

Comment: @Quentin Exactly. ) And it was quite clearly given by error message itself (as XML entities start with '&' and end with ';')